# Terminal opening on running executable in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I created a small GUI application and created its executable in Windows for distribution. Though it runs all right but it opens a terminal (DOS) on starting that remains open till the application runs. How can I prevent this terminal window from appearing or at least make it invisible soon after the program starts?

Comment: You have to use GRacket instead of normal Racket on Windows (other OSes don’t have that restriction). Pass the `--gui` flag to `raco exe` when creating an executable.

Comment: So I have to do it from a DOS terminal (using raco exe command) or GRacket and cannot do it from DrRacket? I believe the exact command: raco exe --gui srcfile.rkt ? https://docs.racket-lang.org/raco/exe.html

Comment: You can also do it from DrRacket if you want. Just make sure you choose GRacket instead of Racket for the “Base” option in the executable creation dialog.

Comment: Hey @AlexisKing , out of curiosity, why didn't you put this as an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: @LeifAndersen Mostly because I didn’t have the time to come up with a well-formatted answer that felt complete, but I figured that comment might be helpful. (I’d want a real answer to include links, as well as an explanation for why the Racket/GRacket division exists.)